# make localhost to be seen by other ip

Tags: ip-address, webserver, localhost

I have installed XAMPP server (and it works fine), but I want to show to somebody what i'm working on, so is there any software that allows anyone to enter my IP and see my local server server
(http://localhost/test to be accessed as http://MyIPAddress/test)

Comment: do you want to show others on the same LAN as you or are you at home and want someone at another locaiton to see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to open the port you are using in your firewall. And if you are using a NAT/router then you have to use port-forwarding to your computer.

Comment: I just added port 80 (xampp is using it) and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free DNS service such as [DynDNS.com](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/):

> **Dynamic DNS Free**
>
> Dynamic DNS Free (DDNS) allows you to
>   create a hostname that points to your
>   home or office IP address, providing
>   an easy-to-remember URL for quick
>   access. 
> We also provide an update
>   mechanism which makes the hostname
>   work with your dynamic IP address. We
>   continue to offer this service free to
>   the Internet community as we have done
>   so for nearly 10 years. 
> Get five (5)
>   hostnames in 88 available domains for
>   free.